# Fire event when img src changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events

I have an image that changes when the user clicks a different thumbnail.

How do I make it reliably get the dimensions of the image that is about to be loaded?

Currently I have:

```
$('#mainImg').animate({opacity: 0.01}, 500, function() {
    $('#mainImg').attr('src', '/cakes/' + file);
    setTimeout(function() {
        center('#mainImg');
        $('#mainImg').animate({opacity: 1.00}, 500);
    }, 100)

})
```

Which is a work around that is a little more reliable than what I previously had:

```
$('#mainImg').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#mainImg').attr('src', '/cakes/'+file);
    center('#mainImg');
    $('#mainImg').fadeIn('fast');
})
```

Function center is for now just:

```
function center(imageElement)
{
    var ph = $(imageElement).parent().height();
    var pw = $(imageElement).parent().width();

    var ih = $(imageElement).height();
    var iw = $(imageElement).width();
    alert(iw)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preload image first to have reliable dimensions. Try something like this:

```
$('#mainImg').animate({opacity: 0.01}, 500, function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        src = '/cakes/' + file;
    preloadImage(src, function() {
        $this.attr('src', src);
        center($this);
        $this.animate({opacity: 1.00}, 500);
    });
});

preloadImage(src, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = callback;
    img.src = src;
}
```

Also modify `center` function to use already available cached variable:

```
function center($imageElement) {
    var ih = $imageElement[0].height;
    var iw = $imageElement[0].width;
    alert(iw)
}
```

Comment: @dsfq I got it to work thanks :) Just need to figure out how to get the parent element height of the main image because now it is saying Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'parent'

Comment: Wrap what ever you use in `$()`: `$(whatever).parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to preload that image, something like this:

```
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    image.onload = function () {
        // Do whatever you want with this.width and this.height overhere.
        console.log(this.width);
        console.log(this.height);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simular to the already posted answers but with a fallback for the browsers that do not support the load event for images properly:

```
$('#mainImg').animate({opacity: 0.01}, 500, function() {
    // run the load event only once
    $('#mainImg').one('load', function() {
        // do whatever you want to do if image is loaded...
        console.log(this.width);
        console.log(this.height);
    })
    .attr('src', '/cakes/' + file);
    .each(function() {
      //Cache fix for browsers that don't trigger .load()
      if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
    });
})
```